# Relocate zeros to the end of the last dimension in multidimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, vectorization

Say you have the following array of shape (5, 4, 3):

```
x = array([[[ 0,  2,  1],
            [ 3,  4,  0],
            [ 8,  0,  6],
            [ 9,  0,  0]],

           [[12,   0, -14],
            [ 0,  16,  17],
            [ 0, -19,  20],
            [21,  22,   0]],

           [[24,   0, 26],
            [27,   0, 29],
            [ 0, -31,  0],
            [33,  34,  0]],

           [[ 0, 37, 38],
            [39,  0, 41],
            [42, 43,  0],
            [45,  0, 47]],

           [[49, 48,  0],
            [51,  0, 53],
            [ 0,  0, 56],
            [ 0, 59, 58]]])
```

in which there is at least 1 zero in each "row" of dimension 2 (e.g. `[0, 1, 2]` or `[6, 0, 8]`).  Is there any vectorized way to relocate all zeros to the end of dimension 2 while preserving the order of nonzero elements.  For example, taking the above array to:

```
y = array([[[ 2,  1,  0],
            [ 3,  4,  0],
            [ 8,  6,  0],
            [ 9,  0,  0]],

           [[ 12, -14,  0],
            [ 16,  17,  0],
            [-19,  20,  0],
            [ 21,  22,  0]],

            ...

           [[49, 48,  0],
            [51, 53,  0],
            [56,  0,  0],
            [59, 58,  0]]])
```

I can do this by iterating over the first two dimensions and rearranging each 3 element list in dimension 2, but in reality, I have a much larger 3 dimension array and am looking for a speed up.

Edit:  This does not need to be done in-place.  Also, in the real problem, the nonzero elements are not sorted and are nonzero floats, including negative numbers.

Comment: The non zero elements in every row seem to be sorted. Is that the actual setup condition?

Comment: No, that is not the actual setup condition. I will edit the question to reflect that.

Comment: Can your elements be negative or is zero the minimum possible value?

Comment: Elements can be negative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach using `mask` -

```
import numpy as np

# Mask of non-zeros elements in the output array        
mask = ~np.sort(x==0,2)

# Setup output array and put non zero input elements into it
out = np.zeros_like(x)
out[mask] = x[x!=0]
```

Sample run -

Input:

```
In [96]: x
Out[96]: 
array([[[  0,   2,   1],
        [  3,   4,   0],
        [  8,   0,   6],
        [  9,   0,   0]],

       [[ 12,   0, -14],
        [  0,  16,  17],
        [  0, -19,  20],
        [ 21,  22,   0]],

       [[ 24,   0,  26],
        [ 27,   0,  29],
        [  0, -31,   0],
        [ 33,  34,   0]],

       [[  0,  37,  38],
        [ 39,   0,  41],
        [ 42,  43,   0],
        [ 45,   0,  47]],

       [[ 49,  48,   0],
        [ 51,   0,  53],
        [  0,   0,  56],
        [  0,  59,  58]]])
```

Mask in the output array where non-zero elements from `x` are to be put -

```
In [97]: mask
Out[97]: 
array([[[ True,  True, False],
        [ True,  True, False],
        [ True,  True, False],
        [ True, False, False]],

       [[ True,  True, False],
        [ True,  True, False],
        [ True,  True, False],
        [ True,  True, False]],

       [[ True,  True, False],
        [ True,  True, False],
        [ True, False, False],
        [ True,  True, False]],

       [[ True,  True, False],
        [ True,  True, False],
        [ True,  True, False],
        [ True,  True, False]],

       [[ True,  True, False],
        [ True,  True, False],
        [ True, False, False],
        [ True,  True, False]]], dtype=bool)
```

Final output -

```
In [98]: out
Out[98]: 
array([[[  2,   1,   0],
        [  3,   4,   0],
        [  8,   6,   0],
        [  9,   0,   0]],

       [[ 12, -14,   0],
        [ 16,  17,   0],
        [-19,  20,   0],
        [ 21,  22,   0]],

       [[ 24,  26,   0],
        [ 27,  29,   0],
        [-31,   0,   0],
        [ 33,  34,   0]],

       [[ 37,  38,   0],
        [ 39,  41,   0],
        [ 42,  43,   0],
        [ 45,  47,   0]],

       [[ 49,  48,   0],
        [ 51,  53,   0],
        [ 56,   0,   0],
        [ 59,  58,   0]]])
```